# C pthread and struct questions

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

Basic function of this code is to get number of counter and thread, creates the counters then create the threads then get numbers of instructions in each thread (format of instruction [counter] [work-function] [repetition] )

```
/* ============================================================================
 * File-global variables
 * ========================================================================== */
static int ncounters = 0;
static struct counter *counters = NULL;

static int nthreads = 0;
static int *ninstructions = NULL;
static struct instruction **instructions = NULL;

struct counter {
   long long counter;            /* to store counter */
};

/* counter value */
struct instruction {
   struct counter *counter;      /* pointer to counter */
   int repetitions;              /* number of repetitions  */
   void (*work_fn)(long long *); /* function pointer to work function */
};

/* ============================================================================
 * Thread function
 * ========================================================================== */
static void *
worker_thread(void *arg) {
    (void)arg;
        int Tcounter;
        int Trepetition;
        char Tfuntion;

        scanf(" %d %c %d", &Tcounter, &Tfuntion, &Trepetition);
```

How do I actually store this three variable using struct instruction **instructions???

```
    return NULL;
}


/* ============================================================================
 * Main function
 * ========================================================================== */
int
main(void) {

        scanf(" %d", &ncounters);

        int i;

        if(counters = malloc(sizeof(struct counter)*ncounters)){
          for( i=0; i < ncounters ;i++){
            counters[i].counter = 0;
          }

          for( i=0; i < ncounters ;i++){
            printf("%lld\n", counters[i].counter);
          }
        }

        scanf(" %d", &nthreads);
        pthread_t threads[nthreads];

        int ninst;

        for( i=0; i < nthreads ;i++){
          scanf(" %d", &ninst);
          ninstructions = ninst;
          for( i=0; i < ninstructions ;i++){
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker_thread, NULL);
          }
        }

        free(counters);
    return 0;
}
```

Is the pthread_create function correct?

```
int
main(void) {

        scanf(" %d", &ncounters);

        int i;

        if(counters = malloc(sizeof(struct counter)*ncounters)){
          for( i=0; i < ncounters ;i++){
            counters[i].counter = 0;
          }
        }

        scanf(" %d", &nthreads);

        pthread_t threads[nthreads];

        if(ninstructions = (int*)malloc(nthreads*sizeof(int)){
          for( i=0; i < nthreads ;i++){
            scanf(" %d", &ninstructions[i]);
            int j;
            for(j=0; i < ninstructions[i] ;j++){
              pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, worker_thread, NULL);
            }
          }
        }


        free(ninstructions);
        free(counters);
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to change the ninstruction into array, if its correct...

Comment: where do you want to store what? you have to pass the correct struct to the thread somehow (and then take care of synchromization)

Comment: I want to store the instruction into struct instruction by using struct instruction **instruction format. say input is 1 D 10, I want a instruction structure stored as counter = 1 , work_fn = Increment , reptitions = 10.

Comment: well, to access a struct instruction** ppData would be (*ppData)->repetitions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, next attempt. This time in pseudo code since this smells like homework...

```
struct instruction
{
   long long counter;
   int repetitions
};


main()
{
  ask #threads

  pthread_t threads[nthreads];
  struct instruction intructions[nthreads];

  while( i < nthreads )
  {
     pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, threadMain, &instructions[i] );
  }

  i = 0
  while ( i < nthreads )
  {
    //now wait until all threads have finished
     pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
  }
}

  void threadMain( void* arg )
  {
    struct instruction* pInstruction = (struct instruction*)arg;
    char cFunctionCode;

    enter protected section, otherwise all threads will ask at the same time

     scanf(" %d %c %d", &pInstruction->counter, &cFunctionCode, &pInstruction->repetitions 

   leave protected section here

   do youtr computes here

   return;
)
```

For protected sections, look up mutex or semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I assume you want to do the following:

```
...
//create the instructions, which is missing.
// be carefull that instruction.counter is not allocated!!!

struct instruction instructions[ncounters];
... 
pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, worker_thread, &instructions[i] );
...
```

And in the worker thread

```
worker_thread( void* arg )
{
   struct instruction* pInstruction = (struct instruction*)arg;

   pInstruction->repetions = 42;
...
```

I hope this is what you wanted...

Mario

Comment: whoops, int *ninstructions will be a dynamically allocated array of size nthreads containing the sequence lengths for each thread.

Comment: I don quite understand the = (struct instruction*)arg; bit , sorry.

Comment: that was missing in your post ;-) . The rest holds still, pass it as argument (fourth argument to pthread_create) to the worker_thread and you can access it within thread main.

Comment: worker_thread receives a void* as argument. You have to cast it back to the correct type so you can access your struct instruction

Comment: Mmmm, so when should instruction be created ? in main or work_thread? and shouldn't instruction be created as array since there is "one or more" instructions per "one and only" thread. I have to use ** but I am not really good at ** =[

Comment: ok, now I understand a little better what u want... depends... do you need the instructions outside the thread?

Comment: Basically User define how many thread first, then define how many instructions within the thread and provide instruction. Say 2 counter 3 thread with 1 instruction each would be , Input : [2 , 3 , 1 , 0 D 5 , 1 , 1 I 10 , 1 , 2 D 5] like that... then it would give , [-5, 10,-5], sorry for my explanation skill